# How to get the location/indexPath of a swipe gesture?

Tags: swift, uiswipegesturerecognizer, indexpath

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SavedExercise")
    
    let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(respondToSwipeGesture))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
}

@objc func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    currentIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
    let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Want to delete from saved exercises?", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: swipedRight))
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .cancel))

}

@objc func swipedRight(action: UIAlertAction) {
    if let unwrapped = currentIndex {
        savedExercises.remove(at: unwrapped.row)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    } else {
        print("right swipe messed up somewhere")
    }
}
```

Saw a lot of answers, but they were all in obj-c and not Swift. The current indexPathForSelectedRow variable doesn't seem to do the trick. Thanks!

Comment: What is the reason to create a custom swipe action rather than using built-in `tableView:leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAtIndexPath:`?

Comment: @vadian Ah I didn't see that method. I'll try that, thanks!